# regarding selected certain rows based on a given requirements into another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have read the csv file into a dataframe using Pandas, the csv format is as follows. I would like to put the rows whose “time column information” is between the interval of `6/3/2011-10/20/2011` into another dataframe. How can I do it efficiently in Pandas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then filter by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df1 = df[df['time'].between('2011-06-03','2011-10-20')]
```

Create `DatetimeIndex` and select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df = df.set_index('time')
df1 = df.loc['2011-06-03':'2011-10-20']
```

Comment: If there are 'NaT' in the time-related column, can i still use set_index?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
data_frame['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['time'])  
select_rows = (data_frame['time'] > start_date) & (data_frame['time'] <= end_date)
data_frame.loc[select_rows]
```

Or, you can make `time` column date time `index` and then select rows based on that as well.

Comment: How to define the 'start_date'? Should I just write it as 2012-02-18, for instance?Any format issue to considered?

Comment: write this way `datetime.date(2012, 2, 18)` let me know if it works